# SQL Server keep only one

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I am using SQL Server 2008R2 and have a table (TableA) that keeps the conflicts between hotel Functions on certain Dates, Time periods and Rooms.

The problem is that it displays them twice, meaning finds that **FunctionA** conflicts in some ways with **FunctionB** and then it displays **FunctionB** conflicting in the same way with **FunctionA**

```
orig_id conflicting_id  event_name  conflict_name   on_date     room_id time_from   time_to conflict_from   conflict_to
22108   22255           FunctionA   FunctionB       15/06/2022  9       07:00       09:30   07:00           09:30
22108   22255           FunctionA   FunctionB       15/06/2022  9       12:30       13:30   12:30           13:30
22108   22255           FunctionA   FunctionB       15/06/2022  30      09:00       17:30   09:00           17:30
22108   22255           FunctionA   FunctionB       15/06/2022  31      09:00       17:30   09:00           17:30
22108   22255           FunctionA   FunctionB       15/06/2022  32      09:00       17:30   09:00           17:30
22255   22108           FunctionB   FunctionA       15/06/2022  9       07:00       09:30   07:00           09:30
22255   22108           FunctionB   FunctionA       15/06/2022  9       12:30       13:30   12:30           13:30
22255   22108           FunctionB   FunctionA       15/06/2022  30      09:00       17:30   09:00           17:30
22255   22108           FunctionB   FunctionA       15/06/2022  31      09:00       17:30   09:00           17:30
22255   22108           FunctionB   FunctionA       15/06/2022  32      09:00       17:30   09:00           17:30
```

In the case above **FunctionA** conflicts with **FunctionB** on **on_date,room_id,conflict_from,conflict_to**
and **FunctionB** conflicts with FunctionA on the **same** criteria.

How could I keep just one of the conflict sets?

Comment: 2008 R2 has been end of life for a few years now. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it. Moving to a supported version is job #1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to delete rows for which exists a duplicate. So use `EXISTS` looking for rows with the same criteria, but switched event IDs or names. At last, in order not to remove both rows, decide for one, e.g. the one where the orig_id is greater than the conflicting_id (thus keeping the row where it is vice versa).

```
delete from conflicts
where exists
(
  select null
  from conflicts same
  where -- same criteria
        same.on_date = conflicts.on_date
    and same.room_id = conflicts.room_id
    and same.time_from = conflicts.time_from
    and same.time_to = conflicts.time_to
    -- but switched IDs
    and same.orig_id = conflicts.conflicting_id
    and same.conflicting_id = conflicts.orig_id
)
and orig_id > conflicting_id;
```